# Вертикально отображение md-tab, библиотека vue-material

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button, menu, tab

Появилась нужда сделать вертикальную таб-группу, которая будет вертикально ориентированная. Есть ли возможность такое организовать используя библиотеку vue-material?
Тоесть md-tab мне нужно привести к виду md-lits внутри md-app-drawer. Или, может, есть другой способ визуально акцинтаровать выбранную вкладку в md-list? Вкладки планируется рисовать через v-for, поэтому создавать для каждой отдельный v-bind:class не получится, да и в целом такая-себе затея. Буду рад любой помощи, за ранее спасибо

```
<template>
  <div class="page-container">
    <md-app md-waterfall md-mode="fixed">
      <md-app-toolbar class="md-primary">
        <span class="md-title">Settings</span>
      </md-app-toolbar>

      <md-app-drawer md-permanent="full">
        <!-- <md-list>
          <md-list-item>
            <md-button class="md-primary">
            <md-icon>settings_ethernet</md-icon>
            Tab 1
            </md-button>
          </md-list-item>

          <md-list-item>
            <md-button class="md-primary">
            <md-icon>settings_ethernet</md-icon>
            Tab 2
            </md-button>
          </md-list-item>
        </md-list> -->
        <md-tabs>
          <md-tab id="tab-1" md-label="tab 1"></md-tab>
          <md-tab id="tab-2" md-label="tab 2"></md-tab>
          <md-tab id="tab-3" md-label="tab 3"></md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
      </md-app-drawer>

      <md-app-content>
        <NetworkParameters v-if="currentTab === 'NetworkParameters'" />
      </md-app-content>
    </md-app>
  </div>
</template>
```